# href no funciona con setAttribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, setattribute

trabajo con nodos appendchild y no puedo asignar valor de href con setAttribute
gracias por leer

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Hay que asegurarse de que `descripcion.textContent` contenga algún valor.

Además, que el contenido de `a`, es decir, el `innerHTML`, tenga algún texto.

Ejemplo:

```js
var descripcion = document.querySelector("p")
var a = document.createElement("a")
a.innerHTML = "enlace"
a.setAttribute("href",descripcion.textContent)
document.body.appendChild(a)
```

```html
<p>/favicon.ico</p>
```